# Android: Including Files Globally

Tags: android

In my Android project, i have a drawer menu and a list menu pulled from the action bar, on the right and left respectively,

I have followed some tips from Stack Overflow and created a `BaseAdapter` for my drawer menu.

When I create a new class i start with (class extends `BaseAdapter`) and this is working just great.

I would also like to somehow include my second menu without having to copyeverything to the new class, the reason for this is i have onclicklistners that reference other classes using intent, so if i add a new intent i need to change it globally across all the classes.

What are your recomendations so i can simply keep added to a single file and include it in the bottom of my `onCreate()` method.

Comment: It is better to use fragments and add drawer menu and a list menu in its activity class.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand anything.